# How to avoid the bug when you cannot join either team - class change and team change keys not working

Tags: team-fortress-2

Sometimes during the map restart, when there are many people joining blue or red team, I usually meet the bug when I choose a team to join, but it fails (due to too uneven number of players probably), and when I try to choose a team again, nothing happens - pressing `,` or `.` doesn't work - neither class menu nor team menu is appearing, and all I see is the map aerial view with scoreboard. The only thing to do is to re-connect to that server (which is not always possible if the server is full and you're still connected but 'stuck', so no player slot is available).

How to avoid this or how to prevent, or how to recover from such a bug?

Comment: "Asked 4 years ago"?!? Valve should have fixed this by now :((

Comment: @Christian Busy with Half-Life 3, obviously ))

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to avoid it I suggest to not try entering more than once in the door of specified team, if the first time fails selected random.

Anyway, if it happens that you got stuck, you can easily recover from this bad situation by opening console and write

```
retry
```

Retry command force a server reconnection and you access again the team selection screen. Sometimes, on busy servers with many people try connecting, this command causes to lose the slot.

For this reason, as suggested by *@Dave McClelland* in comments, is preferable use the command

```
spectate
```

because it fix the problem without forcing a re-connection.

If you really want to join RED or BLU team and reduce the probabilities to trigger that annoying behavior, I suggest to wait that half or more users on the server choose their own team, and then try enter your desired door.

Comment: Well, if I want to select a specific team, that won't help - I just have to try entering that team continuously until it succeeds. However, the idea with `retry` is very promising - gonna try it today. By the way, was this bug ever reported to Steam Support, - is it a "by-design" behavior or indeed a bug?

Comment: Sometimes even `retry` doesn't guarantee you your slot. I tried this on popular servers and I get kicked out with "Server is full." That said, it works much of the time.

Comment: @mbaitoff Good question, it seems well known on community of hardcore TF2 players, but I do not know if someone ever submit this bug to Valve. I added another suggestion.

Comment: @Drake I have found people say that executing `spectate` in the console unsticks you from the "limbo" and puts you in the spectators class without the need of reconnection. Gonna try it also.

Comment: @mbaitoff Yes, `spectate` should work for you without forcing a reconnect

Comment: @mbaitoff I didn't know spectate command, I will try it too. You can update my answer of if you prefer write a new one with that command.

Comment: @Drake I don't want the rep, as the OP had already found that part of the answer for himself by the time I commented.  Feel free to add it to your answer once you confirm

Comment: @Dave McClelland: Wow, that'd be awesome if the servers I went to allowed spectating in the first place.

Comment: @Pyro Find better servers, then :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be related to maximum team number on server for MvM matches and also the robots being regarded as opposing team members (auto_balance / team_balance issue related issue [supposedly... :P])

I had this problem non stop every time I started tf2 for all attempted connects to tf2 MvM matches. Normal matches were fine. **I have found that by joining servers that have 5 or less players resolves the problem for MvM (for me anyway) if more players join the server (5+) the problem does not reproduce, you can remain on that server with map changes and player increases and the bug does not reoccur.**

As the default for server maximum team for MvM matches is 6, joining a game with 5 players or less guarantee's a spot (in theory..) despite how ever many bots / robots their are :) I would say this is a bug that valve should look at, not that I cbf submitting it myself (lol) A simple man with simple goals. Hope this helps someone. If it doesn't, I apologise.

PS: I forgot to add, none of the above commands worked for me. All they did was what they describe.. (eg spectate, retry) with same results. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just type in console: `jointeam [red/blu/spectate]`

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Yes i did do that. and surely it works

Comment: Sorry for the bump. I am commenting here just to say the issue still exists and this is the solution that works best for me. Much better than reconnecting, and sometimes the bug still persists after a `retry`. This is the only one that solves for me.